# DateTime picker directive for Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, datetimepicker, directive

I need to open a calendar, for date fields without using plugins. Is there any directive to use dateTime picker which can be used for angular8 project, or anyone can suggest me how i can work for that.

I need to pick up the date and time along with AM and PM, and display the same when i get data from backend in any format like(2019-12-13T15:25:00).

I am expecting date time picker somewhat like this:

[DateTime Picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Angular way I tried for:

[Angular Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcn7h3?file=src%2Findex.html)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Without plugins, you can use [datetime-local](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_datetime-local)

Comment: i need calendar along with Am/pm selection

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one, part of ngx-bootstrap modules collection https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: i need both datetime picker with am/pm