# How to make checked box value as true in reactive forms using angular8

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, reactive

I have binded the checkbox values dynamically. So now based on check and uncheck, i need to pass the same array of data, with values as true/ false.. But now, even the value is checked it is showing false only and based on check and uncheck values, if i uncheck anyone of the checkbox, the select/Unselect is still checked.

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bods7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
 checkAll(ev) {
    if (!this.all) {
      this.PrintList.forEach(x => x.value =  true)
      this.isAllChecked()
    } else {
      this.PrintList.forEach(x => x.value =  false)
      this.isAllChecked()
    }
  }

isAllChecked() {
    this.all = !this.all
}

onChange(event, item) {
 if(event){
    this.printLists.push(item);
    } else {
      this.printLists.splice(this.printLists.indexOf(item), 1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: first of all, this is not a reactive form. Also your demo does not work correctly, you are missing the onChange function there. Also what is `printLists`?

Comment: yes, i had done mistake in many places, i am not getting from where what to change, i tried by using reactiveform and all but didnt work

Comment: could you please clarify exactly what the issue is. At least I am having trouble understanding. Which array is the issue in?

Comment: I had updated my demo, Here i want 2 conditions to work, 1) When click on select/unselect it is getting checked and unchecked, but if i uncheck anyone of the checkbox, select/unselect box is still checked

Comment: 2) If i uncheck anyone value and console it, i still get false value of that particular item. i mean true/false value is not updating

Comment: when consoled for printLists, i get the same value for that item, even though i have checked and made it as true

Comment: Its becuse you should use FormGroup

Comment: yes i have used formGroup as well, but got list of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been changed your [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gt5kkc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) and **resolved** and **improved** it. 
You should use `patchValue` of the `formArray` in `change` method of `Select/Deselect all` option.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gt5kkc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this without reactive form, this is one option. Leave the `printLists` out, assign `print.value` in the iteration based on `$event.target.checked`. You can use a getter for the select all/deselect all checkbox, which we also use in the function `checkAll`. So based on that, I suggest the following:

in iteration:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="print.value" (change)="print.value = $event.target.checked" ...>
```

the select all/deselect all checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isAll" (change)="checkAll()">
```

Then the `checkAll()` function and the getter `isAll`:

```ts
checkAll(ev) {
  // check if all are checked or not and act accordingly
  if (!this.isAll) {
    this.PrintList.forEach(x => (x.value = true));
  } else {
    this.PrintList.forEach(x => (x.value = false));
  }
}

get isAll() {
  // return true/false based on if all are checked or not
  return this.PrintList.every(x => x.value === true);
}
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdxmv1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: incase if i dont have select/unselect boxes, how can this be handled?

Comment: what do you mean by "handled". If you don't want that select all/deselect all, then just remove it? It doesn't affect the rest of the code :)

Comment: i mean, if i remove that part of code, then change event doesnt work right?

Comment: i hope you will get to know in my demo link, i have removed select/unselct section itself. so want to know how it works with the selected item value and how data goes with that id

Comment: well, like I said, would just remove the checkbox from my stackblitz and assign $event.target.checked to `print.value` in iteration: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-haewdd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, have any idea about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782132/datetime-picker-directive-for-angular-8/59782734#59782734